# world map with ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, maps

Part of my dataset looks like this:

```
    long        lat     group   order   region  transportation_type country
    20.06396    42.54727    6   770 Albania     driving     Albania 
    20.06396    42.54727    6   770 Albania     walking     Albania 
    20.10352    42.52466    6   771 Albania     transit     Albania 
    20.10352    42.52466    6   771 Albania     walking     Albania 
    20.18574    42.42588    6   772 Albania     driving     Albania 
    20.18574    42.42588    6   772 Albania     walking     Albania 
    20.24053    42.33897    6   773 Albania     driving     Albania 
    20.24053    42.33897    6   773 Albania     transit     Albania 
    20.34824    42.30879    6   774 Argentina   driving     Argentina   
    20.34824    42.30879    6   774 Argentina   walking     Argentina
    20.34824    42.30879    6   774 Argentina   driving     Argentina
    20.34824    42.30879    6   774 Argentina   walking     Argentina
    20.34824    42.30879    6   774 Argentina   transit     Argentina
```

`mapdata` looks like this:

```
    <region>    <trasportation_type> <country>
1   Albania     driving Albania         
2   Albania     walking Albania     
3   Argentina   driving Argentina   
4   Argentina   walking Argentina   
5   Australia   driving Australia   
6   Australia   transit Australia   
7   Australia   walking Australia
8   Austria     driving Austria
```

I want to get a world map filled with `transportation_type` in the various countries.

This was my code from the beginning:

```
library(sf)
library(maps)
world <- map_data("world")
world1 <- left_join(world,mapData,by ="region")
ggplot(w_d1,aes(x=long,y=lat,group=group))+
  geom_polygon(aes(fill=transportation_type), color= "grey")
```

and i got this map:

[world map with transportion_type](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HvZIu.png)

only `driving` is visible .i want all transportation type to be distributed around with the respective color as it is in the dataset.

what should i add or remove from my code?

Thanks in advance

Comment: It seems you always have a row with "driving" for all countries, so the layers are overlapping and this one is at the top of the map (an hypothesis from me without the real data). What do you expect from this? You can see and confirm this by adding an alpha = 0.6 or something in your `geom_polygon`, fill colours will be mixed.

Comment: @Guillaume, Thanks for your response. Yes, I have `driving` in all rows . likewise `walking` and `transit` but the frequency of occurrence is different. for example, US has more of "driving " than the other two. but, i want to see also "green " and blue color for transit and walking respectively distributed in countries where i have them in my dataset. what i got from my code  as seen from the map is that i only have "drving". I tried the `alpha=0.6` like this `geom_polygon(aes(fill=transportation_type, alpha=0.6), color= "grey")` but it did not work as I want